# input type="date" text-align:right IOS devices

Tags: css, html, safari

```
/* css */
input{ text-align:right;}

// html
<input type="date" value="2015-05-06">
```

When a input with type="date", text-align:right is not work in Safari form IOS devices，But the other devices' broswer shows the normal.
How to fix it ?

Answer (score 28):

iOS Safari applies styling to an element within the input. Here's what I saw when I inspected it with Safari + Simulator:

```
<input name="example" type="date">
  <div pseudo="-webkit-date-and-time-value">Jan 16, 2025</div>
</input>
```

And the internal element has the following styles applied by default:

```
input::-webkit-date-and-time-value {
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

So you can override the alignment by using a selector that targets that particular element:

```
input::-webkit-date-and-time-value {
  text-align: right;
}
```

https://codepen.io/calvinwoo/pen/ExwMgEe

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `display: block` to fix this.

```
input[type="date"] {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: This worked. It changed my input padding a bit, but that could be due to other reasons in my custom input.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm finding this doesn't work in iOS 15.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
input[type="date"] {
text-align:right;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `text-align: -webkit-right;` like this:

```
/* CSS */
input {
  text-align: right;
  text-align: -webkit-right;
}

// html
<input type="date" value="2015-05-06">
```

Answer (score 0):

Date input fields are not supported by all browsers yet: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Answer (score 0):

Try this , because when you mention its type then it will take below property for date text box only

```
input[type="date"] {
text-align:right;
}
```